# Using LESS for custom styling

Tags: css, less

The current project that I'm working on has a requirement that some customers require their own styling (colours, fonts etc). Other customers will use the default styling lovingly crafted by our designer.

I was drawn to using something like LESS so that we would have a different variables file per customer and import that file into every css/less stylesheet where it's needed. The variables files would reside in a different folder for each customer.

The problem I have is how to import/reference the custom varaiables less file into the other stylesheets.

It's an asp.net web site (not MVC).

Comment: Take a look at [LESS 1.4.0](https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/v1.4.0) (not published in their website yet, but available only on GitHub). You can now use `@import`s with variables, maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote an MSBuild target to compile all the LESS files for each of the different customers using the dotless compiler. The target uses the FileUpdate task from [MSBuildTasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) to amend the variables Import statement in each LESS file prior to the compilation task e.g @import '/css/default/variables.less' is changed to '/css/customer1/variables.less' etc.